# Can we define principal curvatures for a planar curve?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, curvature

I am working with a surface that has an unknown parametrization; however, we can define a function on the boundary. Thus, I can define a curve in a plane. Can I define principal curvatures along the function $y = f(x)$? Additionally, is anybody familiar with formulas which allow me to express the principal curvatures in terms of $f(x)$. I believe I should be able to use the following curvature function:

$k = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}$

for the curvature in the x-direction. Anybody have suggestions/corrections? I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> 1. By "we can define a function on the boundary" do you mean that your surface has a boundary of known shape, possibly a plane curve given by a graph of a function of one variable? 2. If that's right, is the question about how the shape of the boundary determines (or affects) the principal curvatures of a smooth extension of the surface across the boundary?

Comment: Hey Andrew! Thanks for the response. Yes, the surface has a boundary of known shape. At the boundary the function is actually of two variables, f(x,y), however, we know the boundary is only a SLICE of the surface which we can define with f(x,y), and thus at the boundary I fix the x variable, $x_0$, and therefore yes its a plane given by a graph of a function of one variable. The reason I care about principal curvatures, is that I know the entire surface has negative gaussian curvature, thus I want to establish principal curvatures on my planar curve and experiment with limits.

Comment: To clarify, the function of two variables $f(x,y)$ is completely different than my original surface, which I cannot parametrize. We simply know at the boundary we can model the unparameterizable surface with the known equation, $f(x,y)$. But because the boundary is planar, i fix $x_0$, and thus my equation at the boundary becomes $f(x_0,y) = f(y)$

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. While I may not understand the question in detail, the proposed curvature formula looks like it's determined by the shape of the boundary curve, while the principal curvatures of the surface cannot be unless the boundary curve happens to be principal. That is, a smooth surface has principal directions and curvatures at each point; if we cut out a part of the surface, the "principal geometry" doesn't change, regardless of the boundary.

Comment: That last sentence answered my question, thank you!